# jquery animate with nextAll

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an expandable and contractable bread crumb type system.

Each div is created dynamically at different points and may contain data that is somewhat lengthy.  It may have up to 15 divs so each div floated across the screen would expand past the screen.  Because of this when they are created I animate each one by an increasing -700px(-1400px, -2100px ect..).

```
.animate({left: '-700px'});
```

When they are created they stack up as intended.  My intention is to have the nextAll divs slide to the right on hover, and return to their starting position when mouse leaves.

The issue is that the divs do not return to their initially "altered" position.  They simply stack up as a normal float rather than the collapsed position.

Does anyone have any tips on the best way to handle this?

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).nextAll(".selected").animate({
            left: '100px'
        });

    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).nextAll(".selected").animate({
            left: '0px'
        });
    }
}, ".selected");
```

I have a fiddle example of the broken code below:

https://jsfiddle.net/9ke06pfz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the jQuery `+=` and `-=` to add and subtract values from their current value. So instead of setting the value directly do the following to add and remove the value from its current value:

```
 $(document).on({
     mouseenter: function() {
         $(this).nextAll(".selected").animate({
             left: '+=100'
         });
     },
     mouseleave: function() {
         $(this).nextAll(".selected").animate({
             left: '-=100'
         });
     }
 }, ".selected");
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ke06pfz/1/

The `+=` and `-=` are the key here. They take the properties current value and add or subtract from it.

Comment: Works, thanks, but any tips on how to keep from messing up if you slide left and right quickly over the divs?

Comment: Thats tough especially with mouse enter and mouse leave. You can check if any elements are animating and not start any new animations if there are. You can check for animating elements using the animated selector `$(':animated')`